# Network via FireWire cable

Tags: windows-vista, networking, firewire

My notebook works under Windows XP and desktop computer under Vista. Seems to be that Windows Vista has no native support for creating network via FireWire cable. **Is there 3rd-party solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no dice: [TCP/IP is no longer supported over Firewire/IEEE 1394 since Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20050920065518/http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/bus/1394/IP_1394.mspx).

Answer (score 1):

Networking is a spec of IEEE1394, and if you have Firewire onboard, XP, Vista, and 7 will support it.

**EDITED : Molly's answer is correct - MS removed support for Firewire networking since Vista.**

Comment: what were they thinking? no more quick netwroking.

Comment: Well, the usage of firewire networking is really low anyway. it's probably a move to simplify - i had people asking me what's that "IEEE1394 Network Connection" thingie more times than I can count. I think this qn resurrected because of an article (Lifehacker?) on faster iTunes Home Sharing over FW networking.